# autosave original file after edit

Tags: backup, text-editor

How to autosave a backup copy of the original text file in Ubuntu 18.02 after editing and saving the modified version? Mousepad does not have a setting for it.

Comment: That depends on the text editor you are using.

Comment: On my other linux machine (old distro, Fedora Core-3) using kate, kedit, etc., the loaded file is saved with "~" added to the end of the file name if it was modified. On my xubuntu 18.04 I tried various editors but none of them had such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature [does not currently exist](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/buglist.cgi?no_redirect=0&quicksearch=mousepad+backup+copy), so the only thing you can do is to file a bug report on the same site as the previous link and hope the developers get to it soon.

**¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: OK, so how can I file a bug report?

Comment: Just click "new" in the upper left-hand corner of the page I referred you to???  **:P ;-)**  *An upvote before asking more questions would have been nice...* Acceptance after it helped you would be splendid!

Comment: Bug report filed, upvote and acceptance added - thx

Comment: Installed GNU-emacs and now I'm all set, it does save original file if edited. Btw, the Ubuntu software offered snap version of emacs could not access file outside home directory even though permissions were all set. Therefore I decided to do sudo apt install emacs.